# « Voitures de retraité » ou bien « voitures de retraitéS » ?

Tags: pluriel, compléments

J'ai une question vraiment indécidable (et idiote): faut-il un pluriel aux noms qui servent à qualifier un autre nom comme dans le titre.

Par exemple: « la voiture de retraité(s) par excellence » pour désigner la voiture que conduiraient tout particulièrement les retraités, le fromage de beauf(s) , un site internet de jeune(s), les probabilités de récolte(s). etc.

Ma question porte surtout en math en réalité: algèbre de matrice(s), fonction d'ensemble(s) etc. mais je pense que le cas général est identique.
Il y a plus de résultat sur internet pour « fonction d'ensemble » au singulier par exemple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne connais pas de règle générale et je serais étonnée qu'il y en ait.  Je pense que c'est au cas par cas et qu'on peut trouver les deux selon le contexte.

Je préfère :

> La XS est la voiture de retraité par excellence.

parce que je considère qu'une voiture a le plus souvent un seul conducteur habituel. Mais « voiture de retraités » ne me choque pas.

Google renvoie un tout petit peu plus de « voiture de pompiers » que de « voiture de pompier » et un tout petit plus de voitures de pompier que de « voitures de pompiers ». Le pluriel me semble tout à fait logique dans ce cas parce que je ne pense pas au propriétaire ou au conducteur mais à l'outil de travail et ses occupants.

> NR+ est un site de jeunes.

parce que je considère qu'un site a en général plusieurs visiteurs à la fois.

> Avec les gelées que nous avons eues au début du printemps les probabilités de récoltes dans la région sont faibles cette année.

Mais :

> Si on adapte bien les semences à la composition du sol, les probabilités de récolte sont plus grandes.

Je laisse matrice(s) et ensemble(s) aux matheux qui maîtriseront mieux que moi ces objets.

Comment: C'est effectivement un cas où l'accord 'au sens' donne plusieurs bonnes réponses possibles. Singulier pour celui qui l'achète, pluriel pour ceux qui sont transportés dedans...

Comment: On mettra les matrices au pluriel parce que dans une algèbre il y en a plusieurs. Par contre on laissera l'ensemble au singulier parce que la fonction n'est caractéristique que d'un ensemble.

Answer (score 0):

Bon j'ai une réponse de l'académie qui souhaite un pluriel:

> Bonjour,
>
> La question porte sur la prise, ou non, du pluriel de nom servant à
> qualifier un autre nom.
>
> Par exemple, est-ce que « proposition » prend un  « s » dans « logique
> de
>
> proposition(S) » en ce qui concerne le domaine de la logique des
> propositions. Idem avec « logique de prédicat(S) » pour les prédicats.
>
> On peut multiplier les  illustrations mathématiques avec « les
> fonctions
>
> d'ensemble(S) », les « l'algèbre d'opérateur(S) » ou bien plus
> courantes comme « la voiture de retraité(S) » pour désigner une
> hypothétique voiture que conduirait tout particulièrement les
> retraités.
>
> À mon sens, on peut transformer « logique de proposition(S) » en
> «logique pour (les) propositions » ce qui suggère l'emploie du
> pluriel.
>
> Cordialement
>
> En effet, le recours au pluriel dans les exemples que vous donnez est plus attendu.

Bien cordialement,